# singleton class behaviour when calling from independent java classes

Tags: java, static, singleton

This question may be a very basic.But wanted to get clarified.
My requirement is to create a simple cache to store and retrieve the values across my application.So I created a singleton java class having hashmap to store and retrieve the values.

```
public class CacheUtil {

    private static HashMap<String,Object> cacheMap =  null;

    private static CacheUtil appCache =null;

    private CacheUtil() {
        cacheMap = new HashMap<String,Object>();
    }

    public static synchronized CacheUtil getInstance() {
        if(appCache == null) {
            appCache = new CacheUtil();
        }

        return appCache;
    } 

    public Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
        throw new CloneNotSupportedException();
    }

    public void setFields(String key,HashMap<String,String> map) {
        cacheMap.put(key, map);
    }

    public HashMap<String,String> getFields(String key) {
        return (HashMap<String, String>) cacheMap.get(key);
    }
}
```

Also I have 2 independent java classes class1.java & class2.java.

class1.java is setting in to cache

```
CacheUtil cache = CacheUtil.getInstance();
cache.setFields("key1",value);
```

Once the class1 is set the class2 is trying to retrieve

```
CacheUtil cache = CacheUtil.getInstance();
cache.getFields("key1");
```

At this point of time the cache object is different(checked by toString() method on the object) So I am always getting the null for key1 in class2.java.

So would like to know what is the reason i am getting 2 different objects even though its declared as singleton with the static modifier ?

Comment: have you tried it without the `synchronized`?

Comment: You don't need private HashMap<String,Object> cacheMap =  null;

Comment: Why don't you initialize i like: `private HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>> cacheMap = null;`

Comment: @StackFlowed : Please elaborate more.

Comment: R. Suntjens : But cache instance itself always different when retrieving from both the classes using getInstance method

Comment: how can you initiate static field inside a constructor? isn't that suppose to be illegal....? start with removing the `static` keyword from the `cacheMap`

Comment: @Suresh This is very strange. Could there be 2 versions of `CacheUtil` loaded by different ClassLoaders?

Comment: Try printing the values of `CacheUtil.class.hashCode()` to check you only have one instance of that class.

Comment: @PaulBoddington I am using eclipse debugger to debug the 2 classes separately

Comment: @PaulBoddington : hashcode is also different.

Comment: @Suresh Ok well if you've got 2 different instances of `CacheUtil.class` there's something very odd going on. It's impossible to diagnose unless you give loads more details about what you're doing.

Comment: @PaulBoddington I am having 2 batch services runs at the same time.Both need the same ref data from the rest call.So Instead of making 2 same rest calls separately, I have the common code to make the rest call, converts in to map and store it in the cache.       public static synchronized HashMap<String, String> retriveLatest()    {      CacheUtil cache = CacheUtil.getInstance();        hashTask = cache.getFields("latest"); if(hashTask != null) { // make the rest calls  } else { // return hashTask }      } .so when both the services invoking this code,cache instance is different,

Comment: @Suresh in a multi threaded context, make sure you synchronize the methods, or even better if you utilize the concurrency utilities of Java. Try that and see, might fix your problem.

Answer (score 2):

I think problem will resolve simply if you initialize cache map at declaration time rather than in constructor.

```
private static HashMap<String,Object> cacheMap = new HashMap<String,Object>();
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure there is not another thread that override the "key1" value?

Try eager init. 
The instance of Singleton Class is created at the time of class loading:

```
private static final CacheUtil instance = new CacheUtil();
private CacheUtil(){}

public static CacheUtil getInstance(){
    return instance;
}
```

and remove static keyword to cacheMap:

```
private Map<String, Object> cacheMap;
```